# How to use the Bootstrap 5 accordion component with VueJS2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use VueJS with Bootstrap 5's [accordion component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/). I added the `v-for` directive on one of the accordion items, and it "sorta" works....but the styling is off a bit. For example, all the accordion items are shown as "active" at the start. Also, at the start, the first accordion should be opened and not closed.

I set up a codesandbox with VueJS and Bootstrap5 and you can see what I've attempted. However, my attempt does not look like the Bootstrap5 doc example.

My attempt:
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-wozniak-4y3n2?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

How can I correctly use Vue to make an identical Bootstrap 5 Accordion component like shown in [their docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/#example) that shows the first accordion opened at the start and also correctly highlighting the active accordion when clicked? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All items are shown as active because none of them have the `collapsed` class, and non-collapsed items are shown as active.

And the first item isn't shown because its `div` is missing the `show` class.

#### Solution

You can use the `v-for` index to determine which item is first, and bind the result in a [class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) for the appropriate classes mentioned above.

Assuming the `v-for` index is named `i`:

1. On the `.accordion-button`, use a class binding to apply `collapsed` when `i` is greater than `0`. This makes all items except the first initially collapsed and inactive.
2. Also on `.accordion-button`, bind `aria-expanded` to `true` when `i` is `0`. Since we want the first item to be intially expanded, we set this ARIA prop to reflect that.
3. On the `.accordion-collapse` container, use a class binding to apply `show` when `i` is `0`. This makes the first item initially expanded.

```html
<div v-for="(post, i) in posts" :key="post.id" class="accordion-item">
  <h2 class="accordion-header" ...>
    <button
      class="accordion-button"
      :class="{ collapsed: i > 0 }" 1️⃣
      :aria-expanded="i === 0" 2️⃣
      ...
    >

    </button>
  </h2>

  <div
    class="accordion-collapse collapse"
    :class="{ show: i === 0 }" 3️⃣
    ...
  >

  </div>
</div>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-accordion-in-vue-xos0u?file=/src/components/Accordion.vue)

Comment: Just tested...works well! Thank you for the very clear and well written answer.

Comment: @redshift Not sure. Probably just marking them all `.collapsed`. I recommend posting a new question so that someone familiar could provide an answer that might help.